Jest. Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
I am using Jest to test my app.
Problem with test completion in Nest.js when using lastValueFrom, Promise.all, and timeout.
I have a formattedProduct function that performs asynchronous operations, and I use it inside the getProductsList function. In getProductsList, I use Promise.all to wait for the completion of asynchronous operations. Then, I try to write a test that sends a request through the Nats and waits for the response. However, the test doesn't complete, and I receive an error message "Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?".
Here's my code:
formattedProduct function which contains that console log:
 async formattedProduct(
            product_id: string,
            product: any,
            output_template: CardProductTemplate | PageProductTemplate,
            curCityId: any = false,
            customerId: any = false,
          ){
            // another code...
            console.log('product calculated');
            return product;
           }

getProductsList function which should await all formattedProduct promises
public async getProductsList(params: GetProductsListDto) {
  //another methods ...

  const promisesFormattedProduct: Promise<any>[] = [];
    products.forEach((product) => {
      promisesFormattedProduct.push(
        this.formattedProduct(
          product.id,
          product,
          new CardProductTemplate(),
          params.city_id,
          params.customer_id,
        ),
      );
    });
   
    const formatted_products = await Promise.all(promisesFormattedProduct);
   
    const result = {
      formatted_products,
    };

    return result;
}

Controller part
 @MessagePattern([
    'api-gateway.common.getProductsList',
    'api-gateway.common.getProductsListByBrand',
    'api-gateway.common.getUsedProductsList',
    'api-gateway.common.getSimilarProductsList',
  ])
  async getProductsList(params: GetProductsListDto) {
    const products= await this.productService.getProductsList(params);
    return products;
  }

And test file which use appmodule
 import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
    import { INestMicroservice } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { Transport, ClientProxyFactory, ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
    import { AppModule } from '@src/app.module'; 
    import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs/internal/lastValueFrom';
    import { timeout } from 'rxjs';
    
    describe('ProductController (NATS)', () => {
      let app: INestMicroservice;
      let client: ClientProxy;
    
      beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
          imports: [AppModule],  
        }).compile();
    
        app = moduleRef.createNestMicroservice({
          transport: Transport.NATS,
          options: {
            servers: ['nats://nats:4222'],
          },
        });
    
        await app.listen();
    
        client = ClientProxyFactory.create({
          transport: Transport.NATS,
          options: {
            servers: ['nats://nats:4222'],
          },
        });
    
        await client.connect();
      });
    
      afterAll(async () => {
        // if (client) {
        //   await client.close();
        // }
        // if (app) {
        //   await app.close();
        // }
    
      });
    
      it('should return response for unauthorized', async () => {
        const params = {
          rate_id: 643,
          category_id: '0b5d5269-5e79-11e3-bd86-002590552cc0',
          page: 0,
          onpage: 20,
          sort_by: 'relevance',
          sort_order: 'asc',
          filter: {},
          city_id: '90',
          customer_id: null,
          selection_type: 'from_category'
        };
    
        const response = await lastValueFrom(client.send('api-gateway.common.getProductsList', params).pipe(timeout(60000)));
    
        console.log('response get');
        expect(response).toBeDefined();
    
        return;
      }, 60000);
    });


Could it be that something in the // another code part in formattedProduct is not waiting for the promise correctly?

Even if that happens.Doesnot const formatted_products = await Promise.all(promisesFormattedProduct); should await return of formattedProduct  method?

I suppose there could be a missing await somehow in this block:
 async formattedProduct(
  product_id: string,
  product: any,
  output_template: CardProductTemplate | PageProductTemplate,
  curCityId: any = false,
  customerId: any = false,
 ) {
   // another code...
   const somethingFromAPromise = await serviceCallWithPromise(); // ok
   const somethingAlsoFromAPromise = anotherServiceCallWithAPromise(); // not ok - missing await

   console.log('product calculated');
   return product;
 }

